# how to convert a column with a list of coordinates (MultliLineString) into sf/st object on R?

Tags: r, geospatial, multilinestring

I have a dataframe whose one column contains list of coordinates latitudes and longitudes on every row. How can I convert them into sp/sf object (As I understood correctly, in order to make operations and plot them on the real data first I need to convert them into sf/sp objects.)

Here is how one entry under the coordinates column looks like on my data.frame :

[Here is the Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzHuy.png)

Thank you in advance to all!

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: I dont have any code. Thats to problem I couldnt find a function that does the thing I wanted